# Remove last blank line from text file PYTHON

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I have this code which executes an sql SELECT command and returns the result in a text file.
This is working absolutely fine but I'm getting a blank line at the end of my text file which I need to remove.

```py
cursor.execute(sql_p11)
with open('D:\Automate\Output\out.txt', 'w') as myFile:
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[0], file=myFile)
```

Comment: Text files normally end with a newline. Why do you need to remove it?

Comment: I run a utility to further execute that text file. My utility gives error when it finds anu blank line other than the numbers.

Comment: They're different conventions; on Linux they're universally present, but that's not necessarily the case on other systems

Comment: Current Output:
1
2
3
--blank line--

Desired Output:
1
2
3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

- Omitting the newline itself is done by passing `end=''` to `print()`
- Figuring out that you're on the last row of the cursor, which can be done either (a) by rewriting the loop, or (b) by using [`peekable` from the third-party `more_itertools` library](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.peekable)

Rewriting the loop would look like this:

```
cursor.execute(sql_p11)
with open('D:\Automate\Output\out.txt', 'w') as myFile:
    for i, row in enumerate(cursor):
        if i > 0:
            print(file=myFile)
        print(row[0], file=myFile, end='')
```

Using `peekable` would look like this:

```
from more_itertools import peekable

cursor.execute(sql_p11)
with open('D:\Automate\Output\out.txt', 'w') as myFile:
    rows = peekable(cursor)
    for row in rows:
        print(row[0], file=myFile, end='\n' if rows else '')
```

Comment: i tried rewriting the loop with your code, it removed the last blank line but now my output file seems like this:
12345678
Instead, i want my output file in below format:
1
2
3
4
5
6

Comment: Ah, I forgot to pass the file to the `print()`; now fixed. Try it again, please?

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose to use `myFile.write()` instead of `print(file=myFile)`

```
cursor.execute(sql_p11)

with open('D:\Automate\Output\out.txt', 'w') as myFile:
    rows = [row[0] for row in cursor]
    myFile.write('\n'.join(rows))
```